# Film Grain After Render

Tags: rendering, camera

How do you get rid of film grain in a render? I made the sampling high enough and I just want to get rid of the film grain and make the pixels look smooth.

Comment: Are you using Cycles oder the Blender internal renderer with some global illumination? How many samples are you rendering per pixel? If there is still grain, it is obviously not enough. Especially for refractive materials and effects like caustics you will need multiple thousand samples. If you are rendering indoor scenes, portals might help to guide the renderer towards the light.

Comment: I am using blender cycles and 200 samples. I am rendering an indoor scene but there are no windows to place the portal at.

Comment: 200 samples is definitely not enough. You should probably render 2000 or more, depending on your light setup. What you can also try is to disable `Reflective Caustics` and `Refractive Caustics` under the `Light Paths` settings, if you do not need the effects.

Comment: But it would take like 20 days to render 1 scene so what should I do to render faster?

Comment: Since there is no film involved in any of the process, there is no "film grain". Just noise. Bring up.the number of samplea to a point where the noise is tollerable and the render time is still manageable...